# How do large sites handle pushing new updates

Tags: algorithm, networking, weblogic

What security measures are taken and what's the process large sites use when new updates are pushed? Do they replace the current code? Do they create a new directory with the new code then redirect all traffic to that directory? Are the scripts modular? How would you accomplish this as a network and/or programming specialist? I'm quite curious about this as I'm currently working on a project I see hitting a success note in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a large site then there's probably a load balancer sitting in front, so you can take boxes out of service, upgrade the code, perform some verification, and then put the machine back in rotation.

I would think you only need two versions in service in parallel if you're supporting an API and the two version are incompatible in some way, i.e. you need to support a migration period. But there may be other cases.

Comment: Yeah I've actually developed a network topology of that similar to Stackoverflow's. I know enough about networking to get by.

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends on the system, each site can have it own way to deploy depending on a lot of things. However, the concept is called "continuous deployment" and there is a lot of information in the web. Search for it in google.